# How to create and run JMH for ant projects having Junit Test classes in Netbeans?

Tags: rest, netbeans, ant, junit4, jmh

I want to create JMH classes for my ant projects without creating a Maven project (as suggested on official site http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

Basically, I have an ant project with Restful services in which I have added my Junit test classes and I want to benchmark my test classes.

This is my sample test class which runs correctly (ignore any logical errors):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ManipulateBeanTest {

private static EJBContainer container;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() {
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put(EJBContainer.MODULES, new File("build/jar"));
    container = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(properties);
    System.out.println("Opening the container");
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownClass() {
    container.close();
    System.out.println("Closing the container");
}

@Test
public void testInsert() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("insert");
    char code = 'S';
    double rate = 99.00;

    // Lookup the EJB
    System.out.println("Looking up EJB...");
    ManipulateBean instance = (ManipulateBean) container.getContext().lookup("java:global/classes/ManipulateBean");

    System.out.println("Inserting entities...");
    instance.insert(code, rate);
    String exp = "S";

    String object = instance.verify(code);
    System.out.println("JPA call returned: " + object);
    System.out.println("Done calling EJB");

    Assert.assertTrue("Unexpected number of entities", (exp.equals(object)));
    System.out.println("..........SUCCESSFULLY finished embedded test");

}
```

}

I am using Netbeans, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [Ant sample](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/tip/jmh-ant-sample) in the JMH workspace, which you can use to build it into your Ant workflow.

```
jmh-ant-sample $ ant 

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds

jmh-ant-sample $ java -jar dist/benchmarks.jar 
# JMH 1.18 (released 3 days ago)
...
```

Although that is not recommended, and you are better off using the build systems with proper dependency management. Even rewriting that sample to Ivy would be better.

Comment: how can i use this jmh-ant-sample project to benchmark my project, since it will just start to benchmark the method in class MyAntyBench

Comment: jmh-ant-sample is the _sample_ that describes what steps you should make to use JMH from Ant. Adapt to your project as you see fit. You probably need to hook up the annprocess jar into javac task that compiles your benchmark classes, as in sample.

Comment: Do you mean that I have to make changes in my build.xml to actually generate the benchmarks.jar file which will benchmark my test cases? If so, then this is not a feasible solution for me as I have like hundreds of test classes which then I have to configure in my xml file. In that case, can you suggest me some way to automatically generate the benchmarks (just like junit plugin where I included the plugin and started writing my test cases).

Comment: This is what you get for using Ant :) I am not aware of any Ant tasks that make this one easier. But I do not see how hundreds of test classes are relevant here: add JMH annotation processor into a javac task that compiles them. You don't have multiple javac tasks for hundreds of test classes, don't you?